# Parsing AT Command string into integer

Tags: c++, string, integer

I have the following string which ends with an error code which is an `int`. it's like `0`, `511`, `512`, `513`, etc.

I would like to get that number.

The string is like this:

```
+QIND: "FOTA","END",0
```

where `0` is the error code.

This is my trial:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // your code goes here
    char tempdata[40] = "FOTA\",\"END\",0";
    char* res = strstr(tempdata, "FOTA\",\"END\"");
    if(res != NULL)
    {
        int percentage = atoi(res + strlen(tempdata) + 1);
        cout << percentage << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: - and how does that work out for you?

Answer (score 2):

OK I solved it without a parsing or anything else

```
int value;
if(sscanf(tempdata, "FOTA\",\"END\",%d", &value)>0)
{
    
    cout<<value;
}
```

Comment: In your answer, you wrote: `"I solved it without a parsing"` -- This statement is inaccurate, as your program is parsing the string. What you did is, you made `sscanf` do all the parsing, instead of doing it yourself. It is not possible to solve this problem without parsing the string.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    string input = R"(+QIND: "FOTA","END",5)"; // Use raw string literal to avoid escaping "
    smatch matches;

    regex r(R"(\+QIND: "FOTA","END",(\d+))");
    regex_match(input, matches, r);
    
    if(matches.size() == 2)
        cout << "Number is " << matches[1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```